# Perform an action after sprites have touched for 2 seconds in swift?

Tags: ios

How do I perform an action after sprites have been in contact for a certain time rather than when they collide right away?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some frame update method that gets called every frame, and also you can calculate how much time (seconds) elapsed since then. Then, you can do the following:

1. Setup a flag variable named `contactInProgress`, set to `false`.
2. Setup a counter variable named `contactDuration`, set it to `0.0`.
3. When you detect collision, set `contactInProgress` to `true` and `contactDuration` to `0.0`.
4. When you no longer detect collision, set `contactInProgress` back to false and reset `contactDuration` to `0.0`.
5. In the frame update method, check if `contactInProgress` is `true`. If so, update the value of `contactDuration` by adding the time elapsed since the last frame. Finally, check whether `contactDuration` is greater-than-or-equal-to `2.0`. If so, do your thing.